# Angular 2 - Wait for data init from service

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, observable, angular2-services, angular-services

There are 2 services:

- DataService - gets data from the server
- CacheService - subscribes to *DataService* and holds mapped data

and component

- ComponentA - Injects CacheService and has *foo function* that handles cached data

My question is - **How do I ensure that  my CacheService is done with data when my *foo function* gets called**.

**Current solution** that I kinda like but am not sure if there isn't some better *Angular 2* way. Done with Rx.Observables

My solution (Code is simplified):

```
export class CacheService {
    myData:                IData;
    dataLoadedObservable:  Observable;
    private _emitter:      any;


    constructor(dataService: DataService){
         this.dataLoaded = Observable.create(
            e => {
            _emitter = e;
        });
    }

    private cacheData(){
         this.dataService.loadData().subscribe(data => {
             this.myData = data;
             this._emitter.next('data loaded');
        });
    }
}
```

*ComponentA*

```
export class ComponentA {
    this.cacheService.dataLoadedObservable.subscribe(
            isLoaded => {
                if(isLoaded === 'data loaded'){
                    // Now this.cacheService.myData is ready
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably refactor your data service like this:

```
export class CacheService {
    private data$:Observable<IData>;

    constructor(private dataService: DataService){
        //We initialize the data Observable.
        this.data$ = new Subject();
        //We load initial data.
        this.dataService.loadData().subscribe(data => {
            //Once the data is loaded, we have to emit its value from our data$ observable.
            this.data$.next(data);
        });
    }

    //getter for our observable.
    public getData():Observable<IData>{
        return this.data$
    }

    //setter for data, hiding the observable logic behind.
    public setData(data:IData){
        this.data$.next(data);
    }
}
```

The goal behind this refactor is to hide your data behind an observable.

A simple usage would be:

```
cacheService.data.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

The subscription will not get called before you emit data from it (using `next()` call), meaning that your subscription will get called once you actually have data.

Comment: As typescript won't let me have getter and setter with different types like that, I had to use Union type.  
`type DataObservable = Observable<IData> | IData;` 
`public get data(): DataObservable{...} 
public set data(value: DataObservable){...}`Just wanted to mention that.

Comment: @Xquick oh I didn't know that, never tried to be honest (I mean getter and setter with different types)

Comment: So using union type is worthless because I would have to typeguard every use of getter. So I left only getter for data$, removing setter and having setData function as you have in answer. Working fine now, thanks