# Angular 2 wait until variable set

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-services

I need to get values for my variables via `http.get` (must be async):

```
@Injectable()
export class interaction{
private host: string="";
private port: string = "";
constructor(private http: Http) {

    this.http.get("/interaction.json").subscribe((data: Response) => {
        this.host = data.json().host;
        this.port = data.json().port;

    });  
}
```

As the data come asyncronously I cannot access them in method below:

```
interact(data:Request): Promise<Response>{       
    return this.http.post("http://" + this.host + ":" + this.port, data)
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => data.json() as Response)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

So, the `host` and `port` are undefined when i call `interact()` from another service.
Is it possible to await for this variables are set, and then perform `post` request? I wouldn't like to make `get` call inside `interact()`, as there can be many functions using those vars.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: I have used one way to achieve this task is don't subscribe to http inside service file, instead of it you can subscribe to it where you want the data.

Comment: I am curious if this pattern helps at all? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44051264/4614870

Comment: @Brian, getting `null` for that Observable.

Answer (score 0):

i think one way would be like this: you can create a subject and use it as a messenger... :

```
@Injectable()
export class interaction{
private host: string="";
private port: string = "";
messenger$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
constructor(private http: Http) {

    this.http.get("/interaction.json").subscribe((data: Response) => {
        this.host = data.json().host;
        this.port = data.json().port;
        this.messenger$.next(true)
    });  
}
```

and inside the interact (if it's another class, first inject the interaction service and then) do this:

```
interact(data:Request): Observable<any>{ 
    return this.messenger$ //or this.interaction.messenger$
        .switchMap(
            (bool: boolean)=>{
                if(bool){
                    return this.http.post("http://" + this.host + ":" + this.port, data)

                }
                else{
                    // return anything that would help your situation like: Observable.of(null)
                }
            }
        )
}
```

and later call `toPromise` or... on the result

Comment: can't access `this.messenger$ nor this.interaction.messenger$`, do you know why?

Comment: where is the `interact` method placed? outside the `interaction` class?

Comment: it is inside the class

Comment: `this.messenger$` should work then. what's the exact error?

Comment: it's not accessible in interact() method only. The error is: `The 'this' context of type 'Subject<boolean>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<boolean>'. Types of property 'lift' are incompatible`.

Comment: what's your typescript version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160091/discussion-between-gyuzal-r-and-ghb).